# XSLT replacing one elements with multiple elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I would like to replace an element in XML (large) with multiple elements as below:

Original XML:

```
<root>
  <cr>
   <id>1</id>
   <release>A</release>
  </cr>
  <cr>
   <id>2</id>
   <release>B</release>
  </cr>
</root>
```

I would like the output to be:

```
<root>
  <cr>
   <id>1</id>
   <release>Aa</release>
   <release>Ab</release>
   <release>Ad</release>
  </cr>
  <cr>
   <id>2</id>
   <release>Bd</release>
   <release>Be</release>
  </cr>
</root>
```

The principle is, whenever there is //release[text()='A'], replace the element with three above, whenever there is //release[text()='B'], replace the element with two above etc. If the release text() is "C" or "D" or other values, they remain the same values.

My attempt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/> 
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//cr/release/text()">
    <xsl:if test=".='A'">
        <xsl:value-of select="Aa"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It works with one -> one replacement, but how to do multiple? Thanks a lot,

Comment: Can you possibly show you current attempt please? Also, can you be more precise about how exactly many elements you want to show in the about. For example, for "B" you say you want "Bd" and "Be" etc, but why not "Bc"? Do you want to go all the way to "Bz" too? Thank you?

Comment: Is the number of repetitions fixed and known when you write the XSLT? In that case you could use three modes for three repetitions and three `apply-templates` for the three repetitions. I have not yet understood what determines the values of the new elements.

Comment: Why does "A" produce "Aa", "Ab" and "Ad" (and not "Ac"), but "B" only produces "Bd" and "Be"? Can you explain the precise rules you are trying to implement? Thank you!

Comment: Can there also be C, or D, etc. in the input? If yes, what are the **rules** to be aplied to them? Your example is ambiguous.

Comment: Tim, there is no rule (can't be calculated based on pattern) from A to "Aa", "Ab", "Ad" and from B to "Bd" and "Be". The mapping is defined in a mapping table.

Comment: Release with C or D or other values remains the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is a completely generic and short XSLT 1.0 solution**. It uses a *mapping* xml file that specifies the replacements for each wanted release:

(Please, find at the end of this answer the ultimately-generic and short solution written in XSLT 2.0.)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vMap" select="document('mapping.xml')/*/*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="release[. = document('mapping.xml')/*/release/@old]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="$vMap[@old = current()]/*"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**If the file `mapping.xml` is in the same directory as the transformation (.xsl file), and is:**

```
<map>
    <release old="A">
        <release>Aa</release>
        <release>Ab</release>
        <release>Ad</release>
    </release>
    <release old="B">
        <release>Ba</release>
        <release>Bb</release>
        <release>Bd</release>
    </release>
</map>
```

**then when the transformation is applied on this XML document**:

```
<root>
  <cr>
   <id>1</id>
   <release>A</release>
  </cr>
  <cr>
   <id>2</id>
   <release>B</release>
  </cr>
  <cr>
   <id>3</id>
   <release>C</release>
  </cr>
  <cr>
   <id>4</id>
   <release>D</release>
  </cr>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<root>
   <cr>
      <id>1</id>
      <release>Aa</release>
      <release>Ab</release>
      <release>Ad</release>
   </cr>
   <cr>
      <id>2</id>
      <release>Ba</release>
      <release>Bb</release>
      <release>Bd</release>
   </cr>
   <cr>
      <id>3</id>
      <release>C</release>
   </cr>
   <cr>
      <id>4</id>
      <release>D</release>
   </cr>
</root>
```

---

**Note**: Many, differently named elements may be replaced with the same transformation.

**If we have this mapping file**:

```
<map>
    <release old="A">
        <release>Aa</release>
        <release>Ab</release>
        <release>Ad</release>
    </release>
    <release old="B">
        <release>Ba</release>
        <release>Bb</release>
        <release>Bd</release>
    </release>
    <history old="p">
        <history>Pp</history>
        <history>Pq</history>
        <history>Pr</history>
    </history>
</map>
```

**and this source XML document**:

```
<root>
  <cr>
   <id>1</id>
   <history>p</history>
   <release>A</release>
  </cr>
  <cr>
   <id>2</id>
   <history>q</history>
   <release>B</release>
  </cr>
  <cr>
   <id>3</id>
   <history>r</history>
   <release>C</release>
  </cr>
  <cr>
   <id>4</id>
   <history>t</history>
   <release>D</release>
  </cr>
</root>
```

**then this transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vMap" select="document('mapping.xml')/*/*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="release[. = document('mapping.xml')/*/release/@old]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="$vMap[@old = current()]/*"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="history[. = document('mapping.xml')/*/history/@old]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="$vMap[@old = current()]/*"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the above XML document,produces the wanted result** -- where more than one differently-named elements are mapped and replaced:

```
<root>
   <cr>
      <id>1</id>
      <history>Pp</history>
      <history>Pq</history>
      <history>Pr</history>
      <release>Aa</release>
      <release>Ab</release>
      <release>Ad</release>
   </cr>
   <cr>
      <id>2</id>
      <history>q</history>
      <release>Ba</release>
      <release>Bb</release>
      <release>Bd</release>
   </cr>
   <cr>
      <id>3</id>
      <history>r</history>
      <release>C</release>
   </cr>
   <cr>
      <id>4</id>
      <history>t</history>
      <release>D</release>
   </cr>
</root>
```

---

**Finally: An even shorter and more generic transformation can be written in XSLT 2.0**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vMap" select="document('mapping.xml')/*/*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match=
   "*[. = $vMap[name() eq name(current())]/@old]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="$vMap[name() eq name(current()) and @old eq current()]/*"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Do note**: No element name is hardcoded in this transformation !

**An even greater advantage**: We can modify the transformation, so we can pass the URI of the mapping document as a global parameter on invoking the transformation -- thus we can have a single, generic transformation that works with any, unknown in advance mapping.

**Only these are the required changes**:

```
 <xsl:param name="pmapUrl" select="'file:///c:/temp/mapping.xml'"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vMap" select="document($pmapUrl)/*/*"/>
```

**The complete transformation** (the global parameter `pmapUrl` can and typically will be specified dynamically by the invoker of the transformation):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pmapUrl" select="'file:///c:/temp/mapping.xml'"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vMap" select="document($pmapUrl)/*/*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match=
   "*[for $name in name() 
        return
          . = $vMap[name() eq $name]/@old]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="$vMap[@old = current()]/*"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The solution is great.

Answer (score 2):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="release[.='A']">
    <release>Aa</release>
    <release>Ab</release>
    <release>Ad</release>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="release[.='B']">
    <release>Bd</release>
    <release>Be</release>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Test input**

```
<root>
  <cr>
   <id>1</id>
   <release>A</release>
  </cr>
  <cr>
   <id>2</id>
   <release>B</release>
  </cr>  
  <cr>
   <id>3</id>
   <release>C</release>
  </cr>
</root>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <cr>
      <id>1</id>
      <release>Aa</release>
      <release>Ab</release>
      <release>Ad</release>
   </cr>
   <cr>
      <id>2</id>
      <release>Bd</release>
      <release>Be</release>
   </cr>
   <cr>
      <id>3</id>
      <release>C</release>
   </cr>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks, This kinda suits my requirement, the hard-coded xslt isn't very desired.

Comment: @dellair I don't see what advantage is gained by hard-coding the mapping in an external document. Even if I thought it desirable, I would have formatted that document as XSLT and stored the mappings there *as templates* - to be included/imported into the main stylesheet.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: One obvious advantage is that the URL to the mapping document can be passed as a global parameter on invoking the transformation -- thus we can have a single, generic transformation that works with any, unknown in advance mapping.